# How to get the id of an active image in slider using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, laravel

When I click in image of slider I want to show modal with image.

For one image the JavaScript code works fine, but in slider I need to get the `id` of the active image to display it. How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <!-- Item 1 -->
    <div class="item  active ">
        <img src="{{asset($offer->firstimages)}}"
             class="properties slider-dimensions" height="500px"
             alt="properties"/>
    </div>
    @foreach($images as $key => $image)
        <div class="item">
            //the image
            <img src="{{asset($image)}}"
                 class="properties slider-dimensions" id="img{{$key}}" height="500px"
                 alt="properties"/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
<!-- # Item 4 -->
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById(imgId); //id image variable
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Its very easy, you need bind an event to the images available in the slider then you can access the image attributes inside the event handler. If you prepare a pen in codepen.io I can write and explain the code for you.